# 2sxc - BlueImp Gallery App broken after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, blueimp, 2sxc

So, I upgraded to the latest version of 2sxc and had completely missed the fact that the blueimp app had been re-written. As a result, the gallery on my home page is broken, and I wonder if there's a simple way to get the old module to work with somehow without a complete rewrite (the old version was heavily customised).

It's been a while since I used 2sxc and am panicking about the learning process necessary to fix just one module.

Any ideas quickly would be appreciated!
Thanks

Error Message:

> Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object
>   , String ) at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) at
>   ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_blueimp_Gallery__GalleryHelpers_cshtml.<>c__DisplayClass4d.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__2f(Object
>   d) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\stage.cui.edu\httpdocs\Portals\0\2sxc\blueimp
>   Gallery_GalleryHelpers.cshtml:line 60 at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Func`2 predicate) at
>   ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_blueimp_Gallery__GalleryHelpers_cshtml.<>c__DisplayClass4d.b__2e(IFileInfo i) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\stage.cui.edu\httpdocs\Portals\0\2sxc\blueimp
>   Gallery_GalleryHelpers.cshtml:line 60 at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
>   ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_blueimp_Gallery__GalleryHelpers_cshtml.GetImages(String
>   sortMode) in
>   c:\inetpub\vhosts\stage.cui.edu\httpdocs\Portals\0\2sxc\blueimp
>   Gallery_GalleryHelpers.cshtml:line 65 at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) at
>   ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_blueimp_Gallery__Gallery_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\inetpub\vhosts\stage.cui.edu\httpdocs\Portals\0\2sxc\blueimp
>   Gallery_Gallery.cshtml:line 28 at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at
>   ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.Render(TextWriter writer) in
>   C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy
>   Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 54 at
>   ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.RenderTemplate() in
>   C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy
>   Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 65 at
>   ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.EngineBase.Render() in
>   C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line
>   91 at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.Render() in
>   C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\SxcInstance.cs:line
>   222

Answer (score 0):

Basically you shouldn't have to do much at all - 99% of everything is compatible. What's the error you get?

Comment: Thanks for the response... I needed to fix the problem quickly, so I simply dumped a slider in using an HMTL module to get me out of trouble.